# Black screen is coming below the presented view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, delegates

I am trying to present a view controller modally. It is like a pop up view controller.

I am using animateTransition method to animate the transition.
This is my code:

```
extension PopUpViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.25
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        guard let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from) else { return}
        guard let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to) else { return}
        guard let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from) else { return}
        guard let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to) else { return}

        var containerView = transitionContext.containerView

        if toVC == self {
            // presenting
            containerView.addSubview(toView)
            toView.frame = fromView.frame
            popUpView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)
            toView.alpha = 0
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                toView.alpha = 1
                self.popUpView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            }) { _ in

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
                }
            }
        } else {
            // dismissing
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                self.popUpView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)
                fromView.alpha = 0
            }) { _ in
                transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
            }
        }
    }

    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return self
    }

    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return self
    }
}
```

I am presenting this view controller (Presented VC) over the other view controller(Presenting VC) in this way.
I am using the default modal presentation style.
Initially I was using custom but I looked at some posts on StackOverflow and they said to remove it but still, I am getting a black screen(presenting VC) and I can see the presented VC over it.

When I am dismissing the presented VC, again the presenting VC is visible.

Please do let me know in case you need more details.

As per code when `transitionContext.completeTransition(true)` is executed, presenting VC screen turns black

Comment: Please read [mcve] and then [edit] your question showing the _minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem

Comment: I have removed the extra code

Answer (score 2):

You can try your pop-over viewController's modalPresentationStyle to either `.overCurrentContext` or `.overFullScreen`.

> case overCurrentContext:
>
> > A presentation style where the content is displayed over another view controller’s content.

This means it will present the next viewController over the viewController's content.

**So in case of Container ViewControllers:**

So if you have any `tabBarController`, the `tabBar` will allow user to interact with it.

> case overFullScreen
>
> > A view presentation style in which the presented view covers the screen.

This means it will present next viewController over the fullScreen so the `taBar` will not be interactive till the presentation finish.

```
func presentNextController() {
    // In case your viewController is in storyboard or any other initialisation
    guard let nextVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(with: "nextVC") as? NextViewController else { return }

    nextVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
    // set your custom transitioning delegate

    self.present(nextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your new view controller's

```
modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
```

Do this when you initialise your view controller, or in the storyboard.

Comment: I tried to add modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext in viewdidload of PopUpViewController but still the presenting VC turns black when PopUpViewController is presented

Comment: Don't add it in `viewDidLoad`. Set it when you initialise your view controller, or in the storyboard.

Comment: Now animateTransition is not called. The way I was presenting is changed. There is no use of the code now